# How do i pass a custom props from RenderHTMLSource to a custom renderer in react-native-render-html?

Tags: react-native-render-html

I have a component called `RenderHtml` which renders my html:

```
    <RenderHTMLSource
        contentWidth={width * 0.8}
        source={{html: props.html}}
    />
```

And a custom `img` renderer that looks like this:

```
            <Touchable
                onPress={() => props.???}
            >
                <Image src={props.tnode.attributes.src} />
            </Touchable>
```

And i want to call a function inside `RenderHtml` from Touchable's onPress method.
Is there a way to pass a callback to custom renderers?

Comment: i can' get your question, please explain with some more code, where is that function which you want to parse, because i can't get your question perfectly, i am suggesting you to declare that function in global variable, it will be easier.

Comment: Please [validate this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71361032/2779871) if it proved useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common techniques:

### 1. Prop drilling via `renderersProps`

#### RenderHTML

```
const renderersProps = useMemo(() => ({img: {onPress: (uri) => /*do whatever*/ }}), [/*Don't forget deps here*/]);
<RenderHTML
  contentWidth={width * 0.8}
  renderersProps={renderersProps}
  source={{html: props.html}}
/>
```

#### Custom renderer

```
const {onPress} = useRendererProps('img');
return (
  <Touchable onPress={() => onPress(props.tnode.attributes.src)}>
    <Image src={props.tnode.attributes.src} />
  </Touchable>
);
```

#### When using typescript

You'd need to augment the module to include the new renderer prop:

```
declare module 'react-native-render-html' {
  interface RenderersProps {
    img: {
      onPress: (source: string) => void;
    };
  }
}
```

### 2. React Context

[Refer to React official documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)